# What are all the powers of the Protoss Mothership?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Could I get a full list of all of the Mothership's powers, and what its advantages are in StarCraft II?

Comment: It is interesting to note that it ended up being almost identical to the arbiter in classic StarCraft.  Vortex is like a less powerful version of stasis field.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can:

- **Cloak** buildings and units near it
- Use **Vortex** with 100 energy, temporarily removing any units that get too close ([friendly](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=archon+toilet&aq=f) or otherwise) from the map for 20 seconds, and
- **Mass Recall**, transporting your own units from somewhere else on the map directly below the mothership.  This can be used offensively or defensively to great effect.

Despite what [the Blizzard page](http://us.starcraft2.com/features/protoss/mothership.xml) says about it, it *cannot*

- Use "Planet Cracker"
- Use "Time Warp"

Comment: Those videos on Blizzard page is so old, it looks funny ;-). It is good to note that The Mothership's Vortex used to permanently remove the unit.

Comment: That's the starcraft2.com page, which is outdated; the correct Blizzard source is battle.net: [here's the mothership page there](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/mothership). Still, while accurate and pretty, the battle.net unit pages only show part of the information and strategic depth displayed by other sites detailing units, such as [liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mothership).

Comment: Vortex can be used to execute a 'toilet' strategy, usually archon toilet, whereby you suck their entire army into a vortex, and throw 4-5 of your own archons in. The instant that vortex wears off, their entire army is stacked on top of each other. Your archons shoot and splash damage destroys their entire army instantly.